# Delimited comment in C#

Tags: c#, .net, comments

Referring to the below production fragment from C# language standard specification,

```
fragment Delimited_Comment
    : '/*' Delimited_Comment_Section* ASTERISK+ '/'
    ;
    
fragment Delimited_Comment_Section
    : SLASH
    | ASTERISK* Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk
    ;

fragment Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk
    : ~('/' | '*')    // Any except SLASH or ASTERISK
    ;
```

I don't understand `ASTERISK* Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk` part. If `ASTERISK*` means zero or more asterisks, why are additional asterisks restricted by `Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk`.

Please help me understand the above production found in [C# language standard specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#633-comments).

Comment: Isn't that just forbidding the sequence `*/`?

Comment: Sorry. Updated the complete production of delimited comment. It is included in the fragment "Delimited_Comment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fragment Delimited_Comment
    : '/*' Delimited_Comment_Section* ASTERISK+ '/'
    ;
    
fragment Delimited_Comment_Section
    : SLASH
    | ASTERISK* Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk
    ;

fragment Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk
    : ~('/' | '*')    // Any except SLASH or ASTERISK
    ;
```

So a delimited comment is `/*`, followed by stuff which isn't `*/`, followed by 1 or more `*`'s, followed by `/`.

The `Delimited_Comment_Section` is saying that if you have one or more `*`'s, they can't be followed by a `/` (or by another `*`, but that's redundant). The only way to have a `/` is if it isn't preceded by a `*`.

Comment: fragment Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk
    : ~('/' | '*')    // Any except SLASH or ASTERISK
    ;

I can understand ~('/') part. But why should we restrict '*'?\

Comment: `Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk` is already preceded by one or more `*`'s (the `ASTERISK*` bit). Letting a `*` also be part of `Not_Slash_Or_Asterisk` would be redundant.

Comment: Actually `ASTERISK*` means zero or more asterisks, not one or more (which would be `ASTERISK+` ). It is preceded by `*` in the `Delimited_Comment` - but according to the grammar you can also have a slash before the zero or more asterisks.